# Как итерировать число не используя встроенные методы Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, итераторы

передо мной стоит такая задача:

**Написать функцию-генератор, которая принимает целое число и выводит цифры num справа налево. Вам не разрешается использовать встроенные методы Python enumerate или zip, списки, кортежи или приводить num к другим типам данных, таким как str().**

Дело в том, что я не знаю как в условиях таких ограничений реализовать решение.

Буду рад любым советам.

Вот как выглядит функция:

```
def itemize(num):
'''
    >>> gen = itemize(6120025)
    >>> next(gen)
    5
    >>> next(gen)
    2
    >>> next(gen)
    0
    >>> next(gen)
    0
    >>> next(gen)
    2
    >>> next(gen)
    1
    >>> next(gen)
    6
    >>> next(gen)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    StopIteration
    >>> list(itemize(-316798542036498))
    [8, 9, 4, 6, 3, 0, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 7, 6, 1, 3]
'''
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def itemsize(n):
    if n == 0:
        yield 0

    n = abs(n)
    while n:
        yield n%10
        n //= 10
```

Comment: просто добавить один `if`. Исправил